# What are your top workflow resources?

Tags: workflow, 2007

Websites, videos, whitepapers, books?

Of particular interest are resources that extend beyond SharePoint designer into Visual Studio land.

Mine are all cataloged on my [Delicious Workflow Feed](http://www.delicious.com/search?p=workflow&chk=&context=userposts|knowledgethoughts|&fr=del_icio_us&lc=1) but the most popular seem to be

- http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/04/series-of-sharepoint-workflow-how-to-videos.aspx
- http://sergeluca.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!E8A06D5F2F585013!859.entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can [recommend  Workflows](http://www.manning.com/wicklund/) in action by Wicklund.

Comment: I bought it, its great. Plus when you buy the paper version you get .pdf, .mobi and .epub versions.